# How can I print my address book in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I print my address book within Outlook 2013.  I have Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I print my address book?

> Many users want to print their address book, as in the address book
>   that comes up when they click the To button or the Address Book button
>   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).
>
> [image: Address book]
>
> This address book is a "virtual folder" displaying a list contacts
>   from all of your address sources and includes only the contacts that
>   contain electronic addresses (email or fax numbers), and does not
>   contain a Print option.
>
> If you want to print your address book, you'll need to go to the
>   address source, such as your Contacts folder, then print.
>
> You can either use the Print command or Mail Merge to Word. If you
>   want to print only certain contacts, create a custom or filtered view
>   before opening the print dialog or beginning the mail merge.
>
> [image: Choose contact view]
>
> Before selecting File, Print, apply any view except Phone or List if
>   you want to print a Card, Booklet, or Phone Directory.
>
> [image: Address book print layouts]

Source [How to Print Outlook Address Books](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/contacts/printing-address-books/)